# Understanding revert with array of contracts

Tags: remix, arrays, revert-opcode

I have the following solidity file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

error MustBeOwner();
error BookDoesNotExist();

// book contract
contract Book {
    bool public isRegistered = false;
    string public title;
    string public author;
}

// actual library
contract Library {

    address owner;

    // all books
    Book[10] books;


    // rented books
    mapping(address => uint) rentedBooks;


    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    function rentBook(uint _bookId) public view {
        if(msg.sender != owner) {
            revert MustBeOwner();
        }

        if(_bookId > books.length || books[_bookId].isRegistered()) {
            revert BookDoesNotExist();
        }
    }

}
```

I insert it in [Ethereum Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org). It compiles successfully. I deploy it, and run function `rentBook(6)`. A very vague error message is shown:

> transact to Library.rentBook errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert
> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: Where is defined `MustBeOwner()` and `BookDoesNotExist()` ?

Comment: @n1c01a5 lines 5-6

Comment: Yep sorry I was not aware with this new type `error`.

BTW if you call it with another acc than msg.sender it's normal to have this message : ` The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably failing because the books array is empty and you're trying to access `books[_bookId].isRegistered()` over a non existing book. Initialize the books array with values in the Library constructor first.

Or, you can introduce a check before accessing variables such as

```
address(books[_bookId]) != address(0)
```

Comment: The arrays has fixed length `Book[10]` so it will never be empty, the rest is true it is not initialized so every element is the zero address.

Comment: Thanks! Why do I have to cast the element to address 0 if it's of type "Book" ? The initial value of a fixed array having type other than primitive ones is set to address 0?

Comment: What @razgraf wants to say that `Book` is not a struct, but a contract. If you do not intialize it, it will point to the address 0. When you know call `isRegistered` on that address it will not return anything. Solidity checks if the returned value is a valid boolean, but since nothing is returned this checks fails and therefore you get this cryptic revert (as it fails on a low level check).